# ElasticSearch (NEST) Query to exclude specific term results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, filtering, nest

I'm trying to find a QueryContainer query that I can perform on an ElasticSearch result that will essentially filter out any "A" status Items in my resultset. My ProductIndex document contains a field named "StatusCode", and I don't want to return these "A" status' to my search resultsets... I'm having the hardest time finding a way to remove these items.

This query properly finds these "A" status':

```
.Match(qm => qm
             .Field(f => f.StatusCode)
            .Query("A"));
```

But I want to do the opposite (not get all the "A" status items, but exclude them)

Based upon other threads I read on here, I came up with the following query, but it's not filtering out these results:

```
.Bool(b => b
        .MustNot(mn => mn
            .Terms(t => t
                .Field(f => f.StatusCode)
                .Terms("A")
            )
        ));
```

and

```
.Bool(b => b
        .MustNot(mn => mn
            .Term(t => t
                .Field(f => f.StatusCode).Value("A")
            )
        ));
```

But neither removes results that have an "A" statuscode

Kibana value of a result that is still being returned, but has the status "A" code:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to show the mapping for `StatusCode` in the target index?

Comment: Russ- the mapping is just a top level property on the index document that contains a character providing the status of the item. Nothing special.

Comment: Right, but how is it mapped in the index - for example, is it a `"keyword"` datatype, `"text"` datatype, etc.? In addition, how is the client configured i.e. will `StatusCode` POCO property serialize to `"statusCode"` JSON field name?

Comment: Russ - yes, it is a keyword datatype, and the serialization does serialize from StatusCode to statusCode.

Comment: Hmm, I'd expect your second and third queries to work. Might be worth capturing what the client is generating and sending to Elasticsearch, and comparing to a JSON query that does filter out `"A"` status codes. Can capture the request a number of ways, but setting debug mode is probably easiest: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-mode.html

Comment: In Kibana I was able to use this JSON query to properly filter out the result properly - maybe there's something here that can be used to modify the code above to properly filter?
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "statusCode": {
        "query": "A",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Are you able to provide the minimalist example that replicates your finding? I have some thoughts, but it would help to see the mapping, an example document to include and one to exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MustNot filter continues to not work for me - I ended up resolving this by performing two search queryies - one based upon the result set obtained from from the first query

```
.Match(qm => qm
             .Field(f => f.StatusCode)
            .Query("A"));
```

This properly filtered the items to only return the ones I was trying to remove from my primary query. I obtained this document list, then applied this list as an exclusion filter to my underlying request, thus filtering out the items I no longer wanted to return.

Not as elegant as I would like, but got the job done.